# Payment source for payouts using REST API

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

When sending batch payout items via the PayPal Payouts REST API is it possible to use a linked credit card as the funding source? If so is there any documentation for the API around setting the funding source?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: At this point, I've only tried setting the primary payment option in the business account as the credit card. If the PayPal balance is zero the API reports insufficient funds instead of using the credit card to make the payment. I don't see anywhere in the REST or SDK docs the option to set a payment source.

Comment: I have the same issue. It seems the PayOuts API ignore the preferred funding source and does not allow it to be set via REST. Did you find a solution?